# Why do I keep getting null from querying database?

Tags: node.js, express

```
router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
const { query, city, license, position, trailer } = req.query;
console.log(req.query);

try {
    const whereClause = {};
    console.log(whereClause);
    // Handle searchQuery more flexibly
    if (query) {
        const searchTerms = query.split(" ");
        whereClause[Op.or] = searchTerms.map((term) => ({
            [Op.or]: [
                { jobTitle: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { jobLocation: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { licenseType: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { trailerType: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { jobType: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { textPost: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { compensation: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { jobAddress: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { contactPhone: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { contactEmail: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
                { contactName: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` } },
            ],
        }));
    }

    if (license) {
        const licenseValues = license.split(",").map((license) => license.trim());
        whereClause.licenseType = { [Op.in]: licenseValues };
    }

    if (position) {
        const positionValues = position
            .split(",")
            .map((position) => position.trim());
        whereClause.jobType = { [Op.in]: positionValues };
    }

    if (city) {
        const cityValues = city.split(",").map((city) => city.trim());
        whereClause.jobLocation = { [Op.in]: cityValues };
    }

    if (trailer) {
        const trailerValues = trailer.split(",").map((trailer) => trailer.trim());
        whereClause.trailerType = { [Op.in]: trailerValues };
    }

    console.log("Where clause:", whereClause);

    const results = await Posts.findAll({
        where: Object.keys(whereClause).length > 0 ? whereClause : undefined,
        logging: console.log,
    });

    res.json(results);
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in search:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error during search");
}
});
```

This table is filled with data, and in many posts you can find this queried word "job". I tried testing it in Insomnia and I keep getting result null. This was URL: http://localhost:3001/posts/search?query=job (tried many other queries but this I took as an example of one basic).

Comment: if you do query=job -> some fields of your table contains the word "job"  ? 
- another thin is sql-injection, but let's get to this later ....

Comment: try to print generated query and fire same thing in database. I wil be much clear

Comment: Multiple fields in this table contains that word "job".